# How to do session Timeout Handling for Silverlight 4.0 application in RIA services

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, session-timeout

Please help me out in handling the Session time out operation in Silverlight application. I'm using Silverlight 4.0 with RIA services.